# Can we export our flutter package in our another project without exposing our code?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

In android, I can create two application one is parent and another one is child. In child app I just want use only for library(.aar). this library I can invoke in my parent application and this library is secure, means no one can see my code. So as like can I create two application in flutter? And one is parent and another one is child. Using child application can I invoke in my parent application? And it should be secure means, no one can see my code. Only they can use my library in flutter. And please make sure don't use "giving path", or don't use "put pub.dev after using". Because I do not put my code anywhere because of security purpose and also I do not give my code path. So please give me the valid code which should work.

I am serching in everywhere but I can not found how to secure my package code in flutter?

Comment: The reason you don't find any references to this is because it isn't possible.

Comment: So how to secure my flutter package? Because I can not share my source code to anyone!

Comment: You cannot. The Dart ecosystem has always relied on packages being open-source.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for your valuable reply.